# Decimals less than 1 appear as ",x" in output file while they appear correctly in the result window

Tags: t-sql, export, ssms

I am having difficulty with my decimal columns. I have defined a view in which I convert my decimal values like this

E.g.

```
SELECT CONVERT(decimal(8,2), [ps_index]) AS PriceSensitivityIndex
```

When I query my view, the numbers appear correctly on the results window e.g. `0,50`, `0,35`.

However, when I export my view to file using **Tasks > Export Data ...** feature of SSMS, the decimals lower than zero appear as `,5`, `,35`.

How can I get the same output as in the results window?

Comment: May we ask what the final destination of this data is?  I mean, you're exporting from SQL Server, but where is it ending up such that this behavior really causes a problem for you?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Salesforce Marketing Cloud.

Answer (score 1):

Change your query to this:

```
SELECT CAST( CONVERT(decimal(8,2), [ps_index]) AS VARCHAR( 20 ) ) AS PriceSensitivityIndex
```

Not sure why, but bcp is dropping leading zero. My guess is it's either because of the transition from SQL Storage to a text file. Similar to how the "empty string" and nulls are exchanged on BCP in or out. Or there is some deeper config (windows, sql server, ?) where a SQL Server config differs from an OS config? Not sure yet. But since you are going to text/character data anyway when you BCP to a text file, it's safe (and likely better in most cases) to first cast/convert your data to a character data type.